# jquery width returns a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very basic menu with this html : `ul id="menu"`. It has a number of li with `css id="menu_principal"` and I'm trying to use jquery to get

- the width of menu and
- the number of li

After that I want to divide the width of the menu by the number of li to set a width per li.

Here's my jquery code:

```
var nombremenus = $('.menu_principal').length;
var largeur = $('#menu').width;
```

nombremenus returns a correct value, but largeur contains :

```
function (d,e){var f=arguments.length&&(c||"boolean"!=typeof d),g=c||(d===!0||e===!0?"margin":"border");return Y(this,function(b,c,d){var e;return n.isWindow(b)?b.document.documentElement["client"+a]:…
```

I did a console.log on largeur.

Doing

```
var largeur = $('#menu').css("width");
```

returns the correct value in px - I can't then do math with it...

Comment: Reading the documentation helps. you should try it sometime. http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 2):

Well...

JQuery [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) **is** a function. Calling it without braces returns the function itself.
If you want to invoke it, you must pass the parameters needed by the function (in this case an empty parameter set).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  alert($("body").width);
  alert($("body").width());
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

width is not a valid call.

```
var largeur = $('#menu').width;
```

should be

```
var largeur = $('#menu').width();
```

Right now you are receiving a function with it's name. You are not calling function on it

Comment: No problem :) Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `$('.element').width` it will obviously return a function you need to mention that you are calling a function write code like this `$('.element').width();`

Answer (score 1):

`$('#menu').css("width")`  return data as string. So you can use `width` method. `$('#menu').width()` will turn pixels as int. More details [here](http://api.jquery.com/width/). Also you can set witdh with same method.